# How to build OpenCV 2.4.2 on ubuntu for source-level debugging

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, opencv

I am trying to achieve source-level debugging
when installing opencv on ubuntu 12.10.
I a using cmake-gui to generate the makefile from the source folder.
tried setting

```
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE : Debug;
```

make
make install

I do get the .so libs and the include files in the right place
but when I do "step into" in eclipse the debugger just steps over it,
instead of stepping into the source code.

BTW 
in windows I managed this by linking my code against the debug libs e.g cvcore242d.lib